# Cannot Create PublishProfile.xml error creating new publish profile for App Service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a totally useless error message when I try to create a publish profile for my web application

```
Unable to create publish profile <My Project Path>\Properties\PublishProfiles\AppService.pubxml
```

I am trying to deploy to app services in Azure (a deployment slot)

I dont think this is a permissions issue in Azure as I can see the deployment slot in the publish destination

How can I get more information about exactly what the problem is?  I dont know why MS cannot give more information for issues like this!

Paul

Comment: are you trying to create it directly from Visual Studio? Have you tried download from portal and import it in your visual studio?

Comment: It was security related as below thanks @ThiagoCustodio really annoying that the error message couldn't have been more informative!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else gets this please check your security rights

Even though I could see the resource it wasnt enough

I was made a contributor to the corresponding resource group and the error went away